# Can't push commits to master branch: pre-receive hook declined error

Tags: git, gitlab, push

Hi I'm new to using Git and I'm working on one of my Company's repositories on gitlab.  We're a small team, I have changes ready to be pushed to the master branch and I'm getting this error below when I try to do so.

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

When I try to push I'm not asked for any authentication details.  I have a personal access token with these scopes below and an SSH key that I believe was correctly set up about a month ago.  I'm not sure if that's the issue and I'm having a hard time figuring out what credentials Git is actually using.

[image]

However, I was able to create my own local branch (called jacobs_branch), added & committed my changes onto there so it's fully up to date with what I've been working on, and then pushed it to the repository as a remote branch.   But when I try to merge this branch onto master I just get the same error.  Below is a picture of our repo on gitlab.com with my new up to date branch and the older master one.

[image]

So is me not being able to push changes to the `master` branch an issue with me, or is it some kind of permissions thing?  I was also reading that I might need `maintainer` access to push to the master branch (which I probably don't have), but I'm not familiar enough to know for sure.  If there's any other info I can provide or if anyone has an idea of what's going on I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: When Git says *pre-receive hook declined*, this means Git ran some external, non-Git program that made a decision to reject your request. Git has no idea *why* this external non-Git program *made* that decision and cannot tell you; but the program that did make this decision could tell you. If it did, whatever it said, Git will copy through in the previous line(s) that say `remote:` in front of them. In this case, you got: `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.` Read that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someone set a permission preventing you from pushing to the `master` branch

there are many ways to do this based upon different vendors, but you'll need to talk with whomever owns the repository

this technique is normally used to force users to make pull requests to branches